# How to Can I get the default json file about the "editor/context"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to order the item of context in the editor, but I do not know how to write the corresponding json file. So, I want to reference the corresponding default json file, but I can not find the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this path to the settings.json:

On Windows press Ctrl+p or Ctrl+e and on Mac press Cmd+p to bring up the search box. Type in `settings.json`. This brings you to the default workspace/user settings where you can edit your file.

You can also search in the search box for specific items.

Here is some extra info that might help with the editing: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Now I can find the setting.json , but I also can not write the corresponding json script to reoder the order of items of context in editor. How can I write the json scripts?

Comment: I'll check if I can find anything with regards to editing the json file.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I am looking forward to your reply.